# textfield value should be remain while toogling one screen to another in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created a two screen ,expense screen and incomescreen with toogle button to switching expense screen to income screen and visa versa..

here I have a textfield for amount..and it's value should be not changed while shifting to another screen...

(I mean if change  expense screen to income screen, amount should be not changed in textfield...

here is my main file

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isexpense=true;

  void toogleit()
  {

    setState(() {
      isexpense=!isexpense;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: isexpense==true? ExpenseScreen(ontap: toogleit,txtvalue: '',):IncomeScreen(ontap: toogleit,txtvalue: '',)
    );

  }
}
```

and here is expense screen file..not including income screen as both almost same...

(I could make a CustomScreenWidget but don't want to make it....I am given task to solve without customewidget)

here is expense screen code

```
class ExpenseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback ontap;
  String txtvalue;
  ExpenseScreen({Key? key, required this.ontap,required this.txtvalue}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExpenseScreen> createState() => _ExpenseScreenState();
}

class _ExpenseScreenState extends State<ExpenseScreen> {
  TextEditingController txtcontroller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    txtcontroller.text=widget.txtvalue;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    txtcontroller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
          child: Container(
            height: 300,
            decoration: kboxdecoration1,
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  IntrinsicWidth(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (x) {
                          setState(() {


                          });
                        },
                        controller: txtcontroller,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30,
                        ),
                        decoration: kinputdecoration1.copyWith(
                            hintText:
                            txtcontroller.text == '' ? 'Amount' : null),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      style: kelevetedbutton1,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text('Save Expense')),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: widget.ontap, child: Text('Jump To Income')),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your callback to update `txtvalue` like this:

```
class ExpenseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(String) ontap;
  String txtvalue;
  ExpenseScreen({Key? key, required this.ontap,required this.txtvalue}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExpenseScreen> createState() => _ExpenseScreenState();
}
```

then on your onPressed do this:

```
TextButton(
     onPressed: (){
       widget.ontap(txtcontroller.text);
     }, child: Text('Jump To Income'),
),
```

then in your `MainScreen` first define a variable and do this:

```
String txtvalue = '';

void toogleit(String value)
  {

    setState(() {
      txtvalue = value;
      isexpense=!isexpense;
      
    });
  }
```

and also change this in your `mainscreen` :

```
home: isexpense==true? ExpenseScreen(ontap: toogleit,txtvalue: txtvalue,):IncomeScreen(ontap: toogleit,txtvalue: txtvalue,)
```

Comment: @IrfanGanatra I updated my answer. check it out.

Comment: yes done...and do one more favour...while switching to another screen..keypad get off...I want to keep open while shifting screens

Comment: this happened because you build your screen again, there is a work around for that and it is make it focus on textfield when you build your screen in initstate.

Comment: Okay..will go through later

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do it,

1. Use constructor, as pointed by @eamirho3ein & pass it along when accessing second screen
2. Create another Dart file and save the value as static there, for example, create a file ApplicationData and store the value as static for amount. Ensure whenever screen change is happening then store the current amount value in static field for `ApplicationData.amount`.

Access it anywhere.

Comment: .Solved with @eamirho and its helpful your suggestion of creating static...will try with it also...Thanks

Comment: and upvote if question is like that kind.